# Monodromy representations and branched covers

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request, cv.complex-variables, complex-geometry

I need to use the following result (that I'm pretty sure is true):

> **Theorem.** Let $Y$ be a compact complex manifold and $B \subset Y$ be a connected submanifold of codimension one. Then isomorphism classes of connected analytic covers of degree $n$ $$f \colon X  \longrightarrow Y,$$ branched at most over $B$, correspond to group homomorphisms $$\varphi \colon \pi_1(Y - B) \longrightarrow  S_n$$
>   with transitive image, up to conjugacy in $S_n$.

When $Y$ is a compact Riemann surface this is very classical and a proof can be found for instance in R. Miranda's book *Algebraic curves and Riemann surfaces*, Chapter III.

In the general case, I was told that this must be contained somewhere in Grauert and Remmert's work. I tried to find it in their celebrated paper *Komplexe Räume* (Math. Ann. **136**, 1958), but it is written in German and it is very long and technical, so it is difficult (at least for me) to extract from there the statement that I want.

So my question is

> Can someone provide a precise reference for the theorem above?

Comment: So the statement is certainly true for topological covers of $Y-B$. Is the issue that you're not sure if every topological cover of a complex manifold is uniquely equipped with a complex structure compatible with the covering map?

Comment: The hard problem is the extension of the pull-back complex structure from the cover of $Y-B$ to a compact manifold $X$.

Comment: Have you looked the encyclopedia in math series vol 74 title Several Complex Variables vol 7 Chapter 4 by Dethloff and Grauert .You can get the precise reference from there.

Comment: You can also look at SGA 1 page 255 in the arxiv version where a proof of Grauert Remmert theorem is given .

Comment: The article of Dethloff and Grauert  also contains a complete proof. One more thing: To go from a finite covering $p: M\to Y-B$, to an analytic branched covering (in the sense of Theorem 1.3 of the survey), use the following construction. Take a complete Riemannian metric $g$ on $Y$, its pull-back $h=p^*(g)$  and let $X$ denote the metric completion of $(M, h)$. The map $p$ extends to the metric completion and satisfies the properties of an analytic branched covering.

Comment: In the case you are interested in, a small neighbourhood of B intersected with the complement of B is biholomorphic to the product of a polydisc with a punctured disc Z say . When you lift Z to X we get a finite cover of Z which also the product of a polydisc with the punctured disc which then gives what you are looking for without using Grauert Remmert .

Comment: @MohanRamachandran: I think that your interesting comments answer my question, thank you. May I ask you to kindly merge them in an answer, so that the question does not appear unanswered anymore?

Comment: @Francesco Polizzi Thank you .I have posted my remarks as an answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For a modern treatment of the Grauert Remmert argument see Chapter 4 in the book Several Complex Variables vol 7 by Dethloff and Grauert . For an alternate proof using resolution of singularities see SGA 1 page 255 in the arxiv version . The idea of all these proofs is to restrict to the local case . In the case you are interested in, the local problem is filling a finite covering of a product of a polydisc with a punctured disc .